# Why does "continue numbering" behave unexpectedly?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I have an example document that uses nested numbered lists that are continued (the sample document is much simplified, but it shows the same problem).

When I want the last list item to continue the numbering at the same (very first) level, the indentation changes and the number is not what it should be.
Maybe I just don't understand the concepts as the online documentation is very poor.
It could be a bug in list management, also.

So here is how the numbering looks like before trying to fix the last number (item marked red):

[image: Initial test document]

And here is how it looks after I tried to continue the numbering for the last list item (item marked red).
I expected the item to be "2.":

[image: Test document with bad numbering]

Unfortunately I have no idea how to provide the test document.

**Alternate explanation of the problem**

If I have two concurrent numbered lists (outlines), how would I format such avoiding direct formatting as much as possible?

Example:

1) First Step of some procedure A (A1), possibly with sub-steps

2) Step A2

1) First step of procedure B (B1), possibly with sub-steps

3) Next step of procedure A (A3), ...
...

(the list may change between procedure A and procedure B multiple times)

I suspect that LibreOffice has a bug where the actual numbering format, and not the levels of the outlines determine which counters are incremented.
Even after reading the long manual, I didn't understand the concepts behind.

Comment: From your alternate explanation, it sounds like you want interleaved lists. That is, an A list interleaved with a B list where you have part of A, then part of B, then more of A, then more of B, etc. That's not correct, is it?

Comment: @David Yockey: Yes.

Comment: What could be helpful debugging such problems would be a macro that creates comments for each list item listing the paragraph and list style of the item. The only way to check the list styles one-by-one in Writer is to select list styles in the Stylist and click on all the items, a very time-consuming process.

Comment: Good idea, but a bit of work. A quick & dirty way to check list styles would be to modify a list style to change the `.` in the "After" boxes on the Customize tab for each level you're using to something distinctive like `#`. As soon as `OK` or `Apply` is clicked, all corresponding list items in the document will change from, e.g., `1.` to `1#` and be clearly distinguishable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really explain the strange numbering you encountered, as I was unable to reproduce the effect. However, the "Alternate explanation of the problem" concerning how to provide interleaved lists with proper numbering for each list can be addressed using List Styles.

In the example shown below, I created two new custom List Styles, entitled "Numbering α" and "Numbering β" (with intentionally distinctive notation after each number). To start, I double-clicked `Numbering α` in the "Styles and Formatting" pane to start an α list.

To start a β list, I got the insertion point to a blank line and double-clicked `Numbering β`.

Then, whenever I wanted to continue a list or switch from one list to the other, I would double-click the appropriate List Style as needed.

[image: Interleaved Number Example]

Also, if the insertion point is on an item from, say, list α, double-clicking `Numbering β` switches the item to the other list, with any subsequent items in each of the lists renumbered as needed. (Note: if a document has a *very* large quantity of list items, you may need to hit `F9` or select `Tools > Update > Fields` for renumbering to be properly displayed.)

Creating and customizing new lists is pretty straightforward; you can right-clicked in the empty area of the "Styles and Formatting" pane, select "New...", and tweak stuff for a new list as needed. For specific info, see the "Creating custom (new) styles" and "Working with list styles" sections of [Writer 6.0 Guide : Chapter 9 - Working with Styles](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/6/6d/WG6009-WorkingWithStyles.pdf).

Comment: To be able to understand what's going on would probably require reading the style attributes from XML directly. Actually I tried, but the complexity was too much for me.

Comment: Actually what's missing in the documentation is that the actual numbering is depending on the list style, and not on the paragraph style using the list style (I had been thinking the latter). While fixing my document, I found out that there are outline lists with no list style, so I guess that's another numbering scope.
What I had done wrong in my document was to use different list styles for the levels of each list instead of the different lists themselves.

Comment: Yeah, it's confusing and their documentation leaves a lot to be desired. I've never gotten up the steam to join in myself, but if you ever get the inclination you can [Join the Documentation Team!](https://documentation.libreoffice.org/en/join-the-documentation-team/)